# The procedure throws error "Can not insert null in"CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID" although the value is not null

Tags: sql, plsql

It seems that my procedure does not accept the value which I am trying to insert into the customer table. But why? What is wrong with the `cust_id` column?

```
BEGIN

do_new_customer('650707-1111', 'Tito', 'Ortiz', 'qwerTY');

do_new_customer('560126-1148', 'Margreth', 'Andersson', 'olle85');

do_new_customer('840317-1457', 'Mary', 'Smith', 'asdfgh');

do_new_customer('861124-4478', 'Vincent', 'Ortiz', 'qwe123');

COMMIT;

END;
```

This is my procedure:

```
create or REPLACE procedure do_new_customer
    (p_cust_id in varchar2, 
     p_first_name in varchar2, 
     P_last_name in varchar2, 
     P_passwd in varchar2)
as     
     v_cust_id number(6);    
begin     
    insert into Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
    values (v_cust_id, P_First_name, P_Last_name, P_passwd);    

    Commit;
end;
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `v_cust_id` so it obviously is null. Did you mean to use `p_cust_id` in the `values` clause?

Comment: its of no use to create a procedure to do simple inserts a simple insert statment is worth it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable v_cust_id is not set for the Insert Operation but defined that why you get null. 
 What you surely want to do is to insert p_cust_id into the customer Table so 
instead this :

```
 insert into Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
    values (v_cust_id, P_First_name, P_Last_name, P_passwd);
```

rewrite the insert:

```
 insert into Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
     values (P_cust_id, P_First_name, P_Last_name, P_passwd);
```

The fonction will be :

```
create or REPLACE procedure do_new_customer
    (p_cust_id in varchar2, 
     p_first_name in varchar2, 
     P_last_name in varchar2, 
     P_passwd in varchar2)
as     
      v_cust_id number(6);   
begin     
    insert into Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
    values (P_cust_id, P_First_name, P_Last_name, P_passwd);    

   Commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The value is null: I think you forgot the step of converting p_cust_id to a number and storing it in v_cust_id

```
create or REPLACE procedure do_new_customer
(p_cust_id in varchar2, p_first_name in varchar2, P_last_name in varchar2, P_passwd in varchar2)
as   
  --YOU DIDN'T SET THIS TO A VALUE SO IT'S NULL  
  v_cust_id number(6);   

begin     
  insert into Customer( cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    

  --STILL NULL WHEN YOU CAME TO USE IT
  values(v_cust_id, P_First_name,P_Last_name,P_passwd);    
Commit;

end;
```

Try putting `SET v_cust_id = p_cust_id::int;` or similar operation to cast the varchar to something big numeric, and give v_cust_num a value?

Or as Tim says, pass it directly as p_cust_id, let Postgres figure out the conversion.

Or make p_cust_id match the type of the column in the table and get rid of v_cust_id all together

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are passing `v_cust_id` as the `cust_id` column value, yet this value does not get defined anywhere.  I don't see any reason why you aren't just using all the inputs in the `VALUES` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_new_customer (p_cust_id IN VARCHAR2,
    p_first_name IN VARCHAR2, P_last_name IN VARCHAR2, P_passwd IN VARCHAR2)
AS    
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
    VALUES
        (p_cust_id, p_first_name, P_last_name, P_passwd);    
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or REPLACE procedure do_new_customer
    (p_cust_id in varchar2, 
     p_first_name in varchar2, 
     P_last_name in varchar2, 
     P_passwd in varchar2)
as     
     v_cust_id number(6);    
begin     
    insert into Customer values (p_cust_id, P_First_name, P_Last_name, P_passwd);    

    Commit;
```

end;

Answer (score -1):

-- there is no use of this variable- 'v_cust_id number(6)'; 
-- create procedure as-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_new_customer 
(
p_cust_id IN VARCHAR2,
p_first_name IN VARCHAR2, 
P_last_name IN VARCHAR2, 
P_passwd IN VARCHAR2
)
AS    
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, passwd)    
    VALUES (p_cust_id, p_first_name, P_last_name, P_passwd);    
COMMIT;
END;
```